# jQuery mobile page transition

Tags: jquery, html, mobile, jquery-mobile, transition

I am using jQuery mobile page transition feature in my application (HTML5 Mobile App) with:

```
<a href="test.html" data-transition="slide">abc</a>
```

Page transition works fine (the slide animation) with:

```
<a onclick="document.location.href = 'test.html';" data-transition="slide">abc</a>
```

Page transition doesn't works, it just navigates it doesn't slide.

I want page transition to work with the second option.
Please help

Comment: I don't get it. Why? you get the same result from the first option. Why not use the first option?

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that in the first case, JQM does the page change. In the second case, you manually change the page by changing the location. The pages that gets changed by jquery using ajax gets the page transition.
To change transition to slide you can configure default settings `$.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "slide";`.
Use `$.mobile.changePage()` function to change pages. `changePage()` function will do the page transitions for you.

```
<!-- html -->
<a class="testLink" data-transition="slide">abc</a>
```

//js

```
$(document).off('pagechange');
$(document).on('pagechange', function (e, ui) {
    // generally written in pagechange event.
    $('.testLink').off();
    $('.testLink').on('click', function (e) {
        $.mobile.changePage('test.html', {
            changeHash: true,
            dataUrl: "test",    //the url fragment that will be displayed for the test.html page
            transition: "slide"  //if not specified used the default one or the one defined in the default settings
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The document object has no location property, whereas the window object has. Reference:
[document object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp)

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to the fact that jQuery Mobile uses the `preventDefault()` method when following links to enable page transitions. Since you're using `onclick`, this isn't the default action for the element, but a bind for the`click` event.

Essentially, the browser is being redirected before jQuery has a chance to intercept it and animate...

As @Th0mdike has said though, you get exactly the same result from both options, and given that you can dynamically change the `href` attribute of the anchor with `$('a').attr('href', 'new.html')`, I don't see any benefits for doing the latter....

Answer (score 0):

add the attribute

```
rel="external"
```

[documentation link](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-links.html)

> this will allow to load external page